# pass class as parameter for a method in java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Im trying to make a method that creates a new object of a class, but I want to be able to make objects of many different classes, so making a method for each class won't work for me. Is there any way I can pass in a class to a method, so that a new object can be created? All of my classes have the same constructor.

Comment: What? Isn't that what a *constructor* is used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read about [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)?

EDITED

BTW, I do not think that reflection is good way to make your architecture, if you have a lot of classes with the same constructor try to use useful patters like Factory or Builder instead of creating one method with reflection.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand most of it because im new to programming, but I understood enough to know what to do, and my code works!

Comment: And it is a problem, try to ask some skilled(local) java programmer to help you to create design, because answer of sp00m will help you, but it is not a GOOD idea, but it up to you.

Answer (score 8):

You could use

```
public <T> T instanciate(Class<? extends T> clazz) throws Exception {
    return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

and call it like

```
MyObject o = instanciate(MyObject.class);
```

If you do it that way, the classes you want to instanciate must have a default constructor with no argument. Otherwise, you'll catch a `java.lang.InstantiationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to `switch` on a type name and do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for reflection.

Check out this question: [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [Class.forName](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17) might be what you're looking for

Comment: @sp00n I actually liked your answer the most! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

> package com.loknath.lab;
>
> public class HasHash {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>
> ```
>   HasHash h = createInstance(HasHash.class);      
>             h.display();
> ```
>
> }
>   //return the instance of Class of @parameter
>
> public static  T createInstance(Class className)
>             throws Exception {      return className.newInstance();     }
>
> private void display() {        System.out.println("Disply ");  }
>
> }